# Can not apply SMOTE filter in WEKA

Tags: filter, weka, sampling

I want to apply the SMOTE filter in WEKA version 3.6.10 on a dataset, but the `Apply` button is disabled. The input file has the `.arff` format and the first column represents the nominal values. There are also other filters that can not be applied such as the Resample filter, the SpreadSubsample filter and so on. The last version of the WEKA tool does not even include the SMOTE filter.

I want to know if there is a problem with the dataset which is given as input. How should the input data look like in order to be considered by the SMOTE filter?

The last versions of the WEKA software do not even include the SMOTE filter so I used a previous version of the software.

What other alternatives should I try?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the cause of the problem. The labels column should be the last column in the `.arff` file. It seems that in WEKA the first columns are the attributes and the last column is the labels column.

Comment: SMOTE is still available, but isn't part of the standard load. Use Package Manager to add it.